# IntelliJ IDEA Remote JSP Debugging?

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, jboss, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 11.1.1 and I'm trying to figure out how to remotely debug JSPs on a JBOSS 4.01 server.  I can successfully remotely debug servlets but I can't get JSPs to debug.  JBOSS is running with the following `JAVA_OPTS`:

```
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:server=y,transport=dt_socket,address=4142,suspend=n
```

I'm new to the IntelliJ IDEA world so any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I've tried it with JBoss 5.1.0 and it works fine, make sure you have artifacts configured for deployment, I used the following settings:

[image: JBoss Remote]

[image: Deployment]

[image: Artifact]

Breakpoint is hit in JSP:

[image: JSP breakpoint]

Comment: @CrazyCoder The question is for a remote server, your configuration here shows a local server configured.

Comment: @DemiSheep nope, the screenshot shows remote configuration. Local configuration has no Remote staging options.